# Polynomial over integers ring inversion

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, inverse

I do have a finite polynomial ring over finite integer ring. Defined as
$Z_{q}[x]/(x^N-1)$ where $q$ is prime power. How do I find inversion of polynomial in this ring (if there exists)? I know how to find an inversion when polynomials are over $Z_p$ where $p$ is prime or other field but how about polynomial ring over ring?

Comment: euclidean algorithm?